# jQuery: Checking a Radio Button with attr() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Not sure if this is a bug in jQuery 1.4.2 - I can't figure out why this won't work.

I need to check a radio button. I'm using `attr({'checked':'checked'})`, I also tried `attr('checked':true)` - none will work. But if I do `attr('title':'whatever')` on the same radio button, with no other change anyhwere, that DOES work everytime.

Is there some obscure difference between the `title` attribute and the `checked` attribute that I'm missing? They are both your everyday HTML attributes. So why does one work and the other one doesn't?

Here's the code:

```
$('.formradiodiv').live('click', function() {
      //remove checked radio btns
      $('input', $(this).parents('#radiogroup')).each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
   });
      $('input', $(this)).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Edit: Alright, I believe I got it. Apparently it worked all along, and it was just my head temporarily being in tukka tukka land or something.

I was checking the source code to see if jQuery had added the "checked" attr to the radio button I was clicking on: in Firefox, highlight content, right click > View Selection Source. Doing this usually shows all changes to the DOM done by JavaScript, and I was expecting to see the attribute in the source code.

All this time, the HTML radio button was hidden via CSS. That's the reason I need this in the first place - I'm replacing the default radio button with an image.

So in the source code, I didn't see the `checked` attribute on the radio button, hence I assumed that it was jQuery not working correctly. But as soon as I removed the CSS rule, and showed the buttons for testing, I saw that they actually do get checked correctly. Nuff said.

Thank you very much to all who commented. I'll vote y'all up.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jab in the dark:* I suspect that `$('input', $(this))` matches other types of `<input>` elements besides check boxes, and that something goes wrong when setting the `checked` attribute of those elements.

Try to restrict your selector to check boxes only (also note you don't need to wrap `this` when using it as a selector context):

```
$("input:checkbox", this).attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('selector').attr('checked', true);` works for sure!

**edit** I realized in your question that you use object notation `{ 'key' : 'value' }` which will work for the `.attr()` function, but you are leaving out the brackets '{...}'.  To fix your example you need `$('selector').attr({ 'checked': true });`

Comment: well, but it doesn't in this case. That's the whole point of my post.

Comment: @bobsoap did you see my edit, have you checked that out.  If you have and it still doesn't work the problem is most likely with your code elsewhere, I will make a quick jsfiddle

Comment: thanks for adding that Sydenam - you're right, I got that wrong above. Unfortunately, that's not it. It still won't work. I appreciate your input!

Comment: thanks Sydenam, much appreciated. I've updated my OP, it was my error all along.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('input', $(this)).is(':checked')
```

Here's a [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/) that may help.

Comment: he means checking (as in marking) the radio button, not checking to see if it is checked (already marked)